# Oracle SQL - How to return common date period from database (based on start/end dates)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm struggling with returning common period for start and end dates for specific Limit_ID.
My table looks like this:

| Code | Start_Date | End_Date | Limit_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 912 | 08/01/2022 | 14/01/2022 | 44 |
| 905 | 10/01/2022 | 12/01/2022 | 44 |
| 904 | 06/01/2022 | 09/01/2022 | NULL |
| 410 | 09/01/2022 | 20/01/2022 | 44 |

Base query looks like below, it's working but only when time periods have common part.

```
SELECT o.limit_id
      ,MAX(start_date) date_from
      ,MIN(end_date)   date_to
  FROM table1 e
  JOIN table2 o
    ON e.code= o.code
 WHERE o.limit_id = 44
 GROUP BY e.limit_id
```

To make it easier to understand currently it's look like this (I'm getting correct period: 10/01 - 12/01)
[image: Periods]

But it doesn't work correctly for case when Code 904 will include Limit_ID = 44. Then I'll expect query to return 0 rows (as there is no common period). So my question is - **is there a nice way to return results only if date ranges have common period?**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check if max(start_date) is lower than min(end_date)

```
SELECT o.limit_id
  ,MAX(start_date) date_from
  ,MIN(end_date)   date_to
  FROM table1 e
  JOIN table2 o
    ON e.code= o.code
 WHERE o.limit_id = 44
 GROUP BY e.limit_id
 HAVING MAX(start_date)<MIN(end_date)
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy, but didn't thought about it :/ Thanks, it's working for me!